# returns Instance of '_Future<List<MODELNAME>>' instead of json

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

i have an API that returns a list of places as JSON, and it works well on postman, but i cant get it to return it on Flutter.

here is the function that returns all the places

```
Future<List<PlacesModel>> getAllPlaces() async {
  final Storage _localStorage = window.localStorage;
  List<PlacesModel> allPlaces = [];

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${_localStorage['token']}'
  };
  final allPlacesURl = Uri.parse("http://localhost:3000/common/getPlaces/0");

  var response = await http.get(allPlacesURl, headers: headers);
  if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      final decodee = "[" + response.body +"]";
      List body = json.decode(decodee);
      allPlaces = body.map((e) => PlacesModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return allPlaces;
    }
}
```

but it just returns `Instance of '_Future<List<PlacesModel>>'` instead of the actual json list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to pass the json list instead of a list of the placemodel defined by you then go for the following code snippet
and the function call should be like:

```
//function call
var result = await getAllPlaces();// has the json map required and this can further be processed as a json.


//function definition
Future getAllPlaces() async {
  final Storage _localStorage = window.localStorage;

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${_localStorage['token']}'
  };
  final allPlacesURl = Uri.parse("http://localhost:3000/common/getPlaces/0");

  var response = await http.get(allPlacesURl, headers: headers);
  if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      return response.body;
    }
  else{
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: it has the following error

A value of type 'String' can't be returned from the function 'getAllPlaces' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<PlacesModel>>'

Comment: have updated the code snippet please check.

Comment: and if possible please share the response from api as well.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are calling `getAllPlaces` use `await` before it:

```
List<PlacesModel> someList = await getAllPlaces();
```

Comment: i have, now it says '[Instance of 'PlacesModel']'

Comment: This is the list you need. Just type the parameter you want from place model, like `id` or `name` or whatever you have inside. This is because you don't have a to string method in your class. This however answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE THIS:

```
if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      final decodee = "[" + response.body +"]";
      List body = json.decode(decodee);
      allPlaces = body.map((e) => PlacesModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return allPlaces;
    }
```

WITH:

```
    if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      return response.body;
    }
```